# Wordpress add link if item has submenu

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I want to add a button for a responsive dropdown in a wordpress menu, which I can trigger with javascript.
For that I need a custom link with an icon or something like that after the a-tag but inside the li-tag.
How can I check a menuitem if it has a submenu and add a custom a-tag inside?

I've tried the walker and add_filter function, but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this to your `function.php` file, it will add class dropdown to all the parent menus with children (submenus). Then you can target `.dropdown` with javascript.

```
function menu_set_dropdown( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
  $last_top = 0;
  foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $obj ) {
      // it is a top lv item?
      if ( 0 == $obj->menu_item_parent ) {
          // set the key of the parent
          $last_top = $key;
      } else {
          $sorted_menu_items[$last_top]->classes['dropdown'] = 'dropdown';
      }
  }
  return $sorted_menu_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'menu_set_dropdown', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It might be, this is not the best solution, but it works!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're right, there's probably a better solution, but this is the only way I know how to do it. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{ 
      public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
    {
        if($args->walker->has_children)
        {
            //code...
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**